# JQuery: Calling a Function Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have attached a onClick event handle to a tag. On click, I wanted to pick-up an attribute -- let's say, fn; and I want to call the function mentioned as the attribute value.

The following code does not work

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var Test = Test? Test : new Object();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            Test.main();
        })
        Test.sub = function(){
            alert('called');
        }
        Test.main = function(){
            $('.caller').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var fn = $(this).attr('fn');
                alert('calling: '+fn);
                return fn();
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="caller" fn="Test.sub" href="#">test call</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My questions are

- Is it possible?
- What am I doing wrong?
- What could be right approach to solve this issue?

Thanks
Nishant

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes. If you change your link to just have `sub`:

```
<a class="caller" fn="sub" href="#">test call</a>
```

Then this works:

```
$('.caller').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fn = $(this).attr('fn');
    alert('calling: '+fn);
    return Test[fn]();
});
```

The value you retrieve is a string. You can index into an object's properties using a string if you like using bracketed notation (`[]`), so all of these are equivalent:

```
Test.sub();
Test['sub']();
var fn = 'sub';
Test[fn]();
```

> What am I doing wrong?

You were nearly there. You had "Test.sub" in a string, but as it was a string, not a function, you couldn't call it. It would be like doing this:

```
"Test.sub"();
```

....which obviously isn't quite doing what you want. :-)

> What could be right approach to solve this issue?

In technical terms, the above solves the problem. Part of me worries about having the actual function name in an attribute and wants to say "have a lookup table instead", but your `Test` object basically *is* the lookup table, so...

Side note: In this situation, you may see people using `eval`. Usually that's because they didn't realize you could index into an object with bracketed notation. `eval` is best avoided.

---

**Off-topic #1**: Your attribute, `fn`, is invalid (invalid = won't [validate](http://validator.w3.org)). In HTML4 and earlier, *all* custom attributes were invalid, although every desktop browser I've ever seen allows them (browsers let us get away with lots of things). As of HTML5, the demand for this feature was heard and we can have valid custom attributes, but they must start with `data-` so the validator knows they're custom. So if validation is part of your workflow (and it's usually a good idea), you might go with `data-fn="sub"` rather than simply `fn="sub"`. [More here.](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

---

**Off-topic #2**: If you want to save some typing, use `{}` rather than `new Object()`. E.g.:

```
var Test = Test? Test : {};
```

And if you want to save even more, use [the curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

```
var Test = Test || {};
```

Comment: Note on "Off-topic" section: While HTML4 doesn't *allow* custom attributes, I believe that *every (ooh!) major [desktop] browser* (historic and current) has silently accepted them into the accessible DOM, at least since the time of allowing JS access to the DOM.

Comment: @pst: Indeed they have. I usually mention that, but seem to have left it out above.

Comment: I would still use either `eval` or some more sophisticated logic before calling the method to untie myself from relying on that attribute really names the property of `Test` class. In real life it may appear to name, for example, a user-defined `window` function with or without `window.` before its name, and your approach will not work then. With `eval`, you just don't care which object's function you are calling.

So `eval(fn + "()");` is my choice. Just wrap it in `try ... catch`, maybe.

Comment: @Michael: `eval` compiles and executes arbitrary code, which can do *anything*. I just would not do it. The issues you list above are easily handled by parsing the attribute into its component pieces (for instance, "Test.sub" could be split into `['Test', 'sub']` and handled intentionally), without relying on the jackhammer of `eval`. And in fact, the majority of those issues aren't issues at all, but *features* -- containing the scope of what can be done with the code/command/whatever in the attribute.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: This seems reasonable, I agree.

Comment: Really loved the way you explained. Thank you very much. Thanks to everyone for the contribution.

Comment: @Nishant: No worries! You're very kind. Glad that helped.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Your code helped me a lot. Thank You for nice explanation.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<a class="caller" fn="Test.sub()" href="#">test call</a>
```

and:

```
$('.caller').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fn = eval($(this).attr('fn'));
    fn;
});
```